# How to prevent views to replace single quotes with double quotes in HTML output?

Tags: views, 8

I'm using the rewrite option of a view field to generate some HTML. One tag has a data attribute, which should contain an array for later use in JavaScript with `JSON.parse()`:

```
<div data-image-src='["{{ field_parallax_background_image }}"]'>…</div>
```

For `JSON.parse()` [it is necessary to enclose the array fields within *double quotes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/JSON_bad_parse#Property_names_must_be_double-quoted_strings), therefore I have to use *single quotes* for the enclosure of the HTML attribute. The output should look as follows:

```
<div data-image-src='["/sites/default/xyz.jpg", "/sites/default/xyz.jpg", "…"]'>…</div>
```

But somewhere in the process Drupal replaces the singe quotes with double quotes, changing the output to:

```
<div data-image-src="["/sites/default/xyz.jpg", "/sites/default/xyz.jpg", "…"]">…</div>
```

Which apparently is misformatted.

*My question is, why does this happen, where does it happen, and is there a clean workaround?*

I know, that it would be a much cleaner approach to write a custom views field. But then again, this feels a bit like an overkill.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can change [AttributeValueBase::render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21AttributeValueBase.php/function/AttributeValueBase%3A%3Arender/8.6.x) behavior. Is an a JSON object without key/value even valid anyway? I think you would want an array of values (same issue though). You'll probably need to add the data attribute via javascript behaviors yourself.

Comment: @mradcliffe Yes, it works without key/value, but one has to use square brackets instead of curly brackets, then you get an array instead of an object, as far as I know. I corrected the example accordingly. Shouldn't `AttributeValueBase::render()` check whether `$value` contains double quotes, and in this case use single quotes for enclosure?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `"` with `&quot;`? I've not tested this with views, but it worked for me when passing JSON into a data attribute in a Twig file.

Comment: @Hudri This works in the sense of that `&quot;` gets decoded correctly but in the case above you would still get nested double quotes, ergo invalid HTML.

Comment: I've expected an output like `<tag attribute="{&quot; key &quot; : &quot; value &quot;}">`, which is valid HTML. Be sure to check the real source, not just DevTools of the browser.

Comment: But you can also try encoding the outer single quote with `&apos;` instead

Comment: @Hudri Thanks, it works with `&quot;` and as you suspected, the problem was firefox's dev tool, it does not show things as they really are. So, I got it working!